# Header or session issue

Tags: php, html, css

It would appear that after the processing form is posted to it gets to a header and then on the reload the source formatting breaks as the css div disappears and the session doesn't work.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>  
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
    </head>
    <body>      
        <Div align="center">
            <Formlad>
                <form action="loginprocess.php" method="post" target="_self">
                    Username: <input type="text" name="username" Value='' required><BR>
                    Password: <input type="password" name="pass" Value='' required><BR>
                    Submit: <input type="submit" value="Submit" required>
                </form>
            </Formlad>
        </Div>
        <div align="center">
            <Errorbox>
                <?php
                    echo ($_SESSION['Logindets']);                  
                ?>
            </Errorbox>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ok so the data gets posted to the processing page - then the sessions are set and a header bring the user back to the page with messages as to the success of the log in. This is a test document hense the illogical redirect of a successful attempt.

```
<html>
    <?php
        $tmpusername=$_POST["username"];
        $tmppassword=htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass"]);



        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usr","password","database") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $pnquery = "SELECT max(ID) AS ID from table" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$pnquery);
        $IDtemp=(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        $IDmax=$IDtemp['ID'];

        $IDc=1;
        While ($IDc<>($IDmax+1)){
            $pnquery = "SELECT Username from table Where ID ='$IDc'" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$pnquery);
            $Usrtemp=(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
            if ($tmpusername==$Usrtemp['Username']){
                $nothiredu=1;
            }
            $IDc=$IDc+1;
        }

        $IDc=1;
        While ($IDc<>($IDmax+1)){
            $pnquery = "SELECT Password from table Where ID ='$IDc'" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$pnquery);
            $Usrtemp=(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
            if ($tmppassword==$Usrtemp['Password']){
                $nothiredp=1;
            }
            $IDc=$IDc+1;
        }

        $IDc=1;
        While ($IDc<>($IDmax+1)){
            $pnquery = "SELECT Username from table Where ID ='$IDc'" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$pnquery);
            $Usrtemp=(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
            if ($tmpusername==$Usrtemp['Username']){
                $hiredu=1;
            }
            $IDc=$IDc+1;
        }

        $IDc=1;
        While ($IDc<>($IDmax+1)){
            $pnquery = "SELECT Password from table Where ID ='$IDc'" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$pnquery);
            $Usrtemp=(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
            if ($tmppassword==$Usrtemp['Password']){
                $hiredp=1;
            }
            $IDc=$IDc+1;
        }
        If (($nothiredu==1) and ($nothiredp==1)){
            $_SESSION['Logindets']='STUFfff.......';
            header("Location: http://localhost/Login.php");
            exit;
        }
        if (($hiredu==1) and ($hiredp==1)){

            $pnquery = "SELECT ID from table Where Username ='$tmpusername'" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$pnquery);
            $IDtemp=(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
            $_SESSION['Logindets']='YOUR IN SON WHOOOP';
            $_SESSION['Loginsuc']=1;
            $_SESSION['LoginTime'] = time();
            $_SESSION['LoginID'] = $IDtemp['ID'];
            $_SESSION['LoginUsr'] = $tmpusername;
            header("Location: http://localhost/Login.php");
            // put this ------ if($_SESSION['loginTime'] + 1000 < time()){ ------ on each page where the login is being used. 
        }
        if (($hiredu==1) and ($hiredp==0)){
            //Username is correct incorrect password
            $_SESSION['Logindets']='Your Username or Password is incorrect';
            header("Location: http://localhost/Login.php");
            exit;
        }

        if ($hiredu==0){
            $_SESSION['Logindets']='Your Username or Password is incorrect';
            header("Location: http://localhost/Login.php"); 
        } 

    ?>

</html>
```

So my question is no longer what is wrong with my form but what is wrong with my php?

Comment: Sidenote: You have `session_start();` but it's not inside your second body of code. It needs to be inside all files using sessions, *if you haven't already done so.*

Comment: Asking for a quick answer is the worst way to get a quick answer.

Comment: *Plus,* you're mixing MySQL functions. Change `or die(mysql_error())` to `or die(mysqli_error())`

Comment: Ok thats all changed freddyboi

Comment: can i upload screenshots here?

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); on the top of the second file and post the output

Comment: You **REALLY** need to fix this code. Why are you running all those queries in a loop? Why can't you have `select username,password FROM yourtable WHERE username='foo' and password='foo'`?

Comment: where and what is the error u are getting? is it that u are not redirected to new page.

Comment: Marc - i realise thats a more efficient system in your eyes. but there is a reason its in a loop. I can't remember why. but there is a reason. Angelo - i'll get back to you

Comment: Okay so i have discovered some stuff. If i reload the page from the local host the session works. but the header redirect ruins the page. a grey box surrounds the session error. and it disappears when I redirect with a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two header always gives some error try using die() in above code instead of exit()

> OR

Use Meta tag

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://localhost/Login.php">
```

Comment: Guys You will be soooo angry.

Comment: I spent 3 day going through again and again

Comment: still never use two header redirection and dont use exit() try using meta tag it always help for long run.Try to implement changes given into comment will make ur code better.